# 2 popovers opening on click on single button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

//html

```
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="adduserteam" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="select atleast one employee!" data-trigger="focus">Add</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="removeuserteam" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="select atleast one employee!" data-trigger="focus">Remove</button>
    </div>

// on click function//

$('#removeuserteam').on('click',function() {
    if(teamuser.rows('.selected').data().length > 0){   
        $.ajax({
                    url : "../../rest/teamRest/removeFromTeam",
                    type : "POST",
                    dataType : "json",
                    contentType : "application/json",
                    data:       JSON.stringify(test.emp),
                    success : function(data) {
                            teamuser.ajax.reload();
                            alert("success deleteRule: ");
                            $('#addteammodal').modal('hide');
                            },
                            error : function(request,status,error) {
                                    teamuser.ajax.reload();
                                    alert("error deleteRule: ");
                                }
                                });
                                $('.edit').removeClass('edit');
                        }
                        else
                            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('show');

                });
```

in this code i have the onclick function , html part for the buttons  , if i click on the removeuser button and i have one more button of same config even that popover is opening

Comment: Can you show your onclick function, inside which you are calling `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('show');`?

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is both `button` has

```
data-toggle="popover"
```

and hence both the popovers opens.

Instead do it by `id` or `$(this)`:

```
$('#adduserteam').click(function(){
   $(this).popover('show');
})
$('#removeuserteam').click(function(){
   $(this).popover('show');
})
```

After you updated your question:

```
$('#removeuserteam').on('click',function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if(teamuser.rows('.selected').data().length > 0){   
        $.ajax({
                    url : "../../rest/teamRest/removeFromTeam",
                    type : "POST",
                    dataType : "json",
                    contentType : "application/json",
                    data:       JSON.stringify(test.emp),
                    success : function(data) {
                            teamuser.ajax.reload();
                            alert("success deleteRule: ");
                            $('#addteammodal').modal('hide');
                            },
                            error : function(request,status,error) {
                                    teamuser.ajax.reload();
                                    alert("error deleteRule: ");
                                }
                                });
                                $('.edit').removeClass('edit');
                        }
                        else
                            $this.popover('show');

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

That works fine out of the box:

Live example: http://jsbin.com/sanonu/1/edit?html,js,output

Something in your click event might trigger the second one... though, **I personally would change** the trigger to `over` instead of `click/focus` so as UX, you will not have two actions in one click...

if you can't, simply use the **Tooltip** instead of the **Popover**.